# Proof that one block of a matrix exponential has to be invertible using $e^A e^{-A} = \mathbb{1}_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

In a physics related problem I am given a matrix $\mathcal{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, defined by

$$\mathcal{M} = e^{\mathcal{R}} = \left(\begin{array}{c|c} \mathcal{A} & \mathcal{B} \\ \hline\mathcal{C} & \mathcal{D} \end{array} \right),$$

where

$$ \mathcal{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k} \quad \mathcal{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times (N-k)} \quad \mathcal{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N-k) \times k} \quad \mathcal{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N-k) \times (N-k)} $$

whose elements are all different from zero but not possible (at least not easy) to specify in general. The only matrix I can specify in general is $\mathcal{R}$ whose elements add up to $0$ in each row and thus $\sum_j (\mathcal{M})_{ij} = 1$.

Instead of using the knowledge about the elements $(\mathcal{R})_{ij}$, I want to use that due to the application of the matrix exponential, I know that $\det(\mathcal{M}) \neq 0$ since $\mathcal{M}^{-1}$ always exists.

My first idea to proof that $\mathcal{D}^{-1}$ exists if $\mathcal{M}^{-1}$ exists was a circular proof, where I assumed that the inverse of $\mathcal{D}$ exists to show that it exists using the formula

$$ \det(\mathcal{M}) = \det(\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}\mathcal{D}^{-1}\mathcal{C}) \times \det(\mathcal{D}) \neq 0.$$

It can thus be omitted - My second idea was to use the general definition of the inverse of a block matrix to conclude that since the inverse of a matrix exponential always exists, $\mathcal{D}^{-1}$ has to exist as well (using a formula of the kind shown in the section "Block matrix inversion" on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix and the knowledge that $\mathbf{P} = \mathcal{M}^{-1}$ exists, where $\mathbf{P}$ is in the notation of the wikipedia article).

Do you think it is possible to show invertibility of $\mathcal{D}$ by the given properties of $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: No it doesn't: it is indeed circular.

Comment: As you said, your ''proof'' does not have sense. You assume that $\mathcal{D}$ is invertible to prove it is invertible.

Comment: alright, thank you :)

Comment: How would you show the existence of $\mathcal{D}^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, how did *you* do? (since you claim having been able to conclude with a second approach).

Comment: do the rows add to 1, or to 0? I'm afraid that the question is too complicated and confusing. It could be better if you formulate your initial problem that you are trying to solve (if there is some)

Comment: The rows of $\mathcal R$ add to $0$, those of $\mathcal M=e^{\mathcal R}$ add to $1$. The OP reformulated his problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540810).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly; however, the exponential of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -x\\
x & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has positive lower-right coordinate for $x=1$ and negative for $x=2$. So it is zero for some $x$.

Comment: @Michael Even with these additional constraints (which you didn't mention in the original question), PeterFanek's counterexample still shows that $\mathcal D$ is not necessarily invertible: just put sufficiently small diagonal terms in his matrix and use the continuity of the exponential map.

Comment: @Michael Ok, so replace the zeros in my counter-example by some small $\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon$

Comment: I am sure you know already that the lower-right co-ordinate is zero at exactly $\pi/2$!

Comment: Oh, sorry for my ignoracne, but is clear now @preferred_anon :-)

Comment: Since the OP added the constraint $\sum_j (\mathcal{M})_{ij} = 1$ ($\forall i$), this answer is not a counterexample any longer.